# Why doesn't the code enter into `if` clause?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

Here is the code snippet:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT occurrence_number FROM occurrence WHERE word_id = '$word_id' AND page_id = '$page_id'");

$array_row = mysql_fetch_array($check);
if($array_row['occurrence_number']){
   mysql_query("UPDATE occurrence SET occurrence_number = occurrence_number +1  WHERE word_id = '$word_id'"); 
   print "Updating";
}else{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO occurrence (word_id,page_id) VALUES ($word_id,$page_id)");
   print "Indexing: $cur_word<br>";
}
```

What I want the query to do:

If in the table `occurrence`, there exists a row where `word_id ='$word_id'` and `page_id = '$page_id'`, then update that `occurrence_number` column of that row after adding 1 to it.

What I am getting when executing this query:

The code never enters `if` clause. Everytime I execute the code, a new row is generated with the same `word_id`, `page_id`, default value of `occurrence_number`(which is set to `0`) and  `occurrence_id`(which is auto-incrementing and the primary key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **is_numeric**() like

```
if(is_numeric($array_row['occurrence_number'])){
     mysql_query("UPDATE occurrence SET occurrence_number = occurrence_number +1  WHERE word_id = '$word_id'"); 
     print "Updating";
}else{
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO occurrence (word_id,page_id) VALUES ($word_id,$page_id)");
     print "Indexing: $cur_word<br>";
}
```

Or you can simply try like

```
if($array_row['occurrence_number'] || $array_row['occurrence_number'] == '0'){
```

And main thing if you try with **mysql_fetch_array with while loop** it will get through all the relative records or else it will return only one record

```
while($array_row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
    //Put here the code...if else 
}
```

And also dont use mysql_* functions due to they are **depricated**.Instead you can use **mysqli**_* or **PDO** statements

Answer (score 1):

It's because MYSQL returns more then 1 row.
Try to use **mysql_fetch_row** instead of **mysql_fetch_array**.

Or just do it like this:

```
while($my_fetch_var = mysql_fetch_array($check))
{ your if clause }
```

P.S.: Also try to check, how many rows do you have:

```
echo count($array_row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check if `row` exists rather than checking actual value

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT occurrence_number FROM occurrence WHERE word_id = '$word_id' AND page_id = '$page_id'");
if($array_row = mysql_fetch_array($check))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE occurrence SET occurrence_number = occurrence_number +1  WHERE word_id = '$word_id'"); 
   print "Updating";
}else{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO occurrence (word_id,page_id) VALUES ($word_id,$page_id)");
   print "Indexing: $cur_word<br>";
}
```

Beware that `mysql_*` function are deprecated, better to use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $array_row['occurrence_number'] == '0' || $array_row['occurrence_number']  ){

while($array_row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {

mysql_query("UPDATE occurrence SET occurrence_number = occurrence_number +1  WHERE     word_id = '$word_id'"); 
print "Updating";
}
```